# Permision denied for dotnet

Tags: .net-core

I recently installed dotnet 5.0 on Pop OS but whenever I try to use it it says that I don't have permission.

For example, if I just try to run the command `dotnet` it gives the the message

`cannot snap-exec: cannot exec "/snap/dotnet-sdk/144/snap/command-chain/snapcraft-runner": permission denied`

When I run the command as the root user it works perfectly fine.

I don't know if this is because I installed dotnet as a snap package

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/4446

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and unfortunately the `dotnet` issue page was not working.

To fix this issue I had to install the package with `apt` instead of `snap`.

```
sudo snap remove dotnet-sdk // if needed

wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb

sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb

sudo apt update

sudo apt install apt-transport-https

sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-5.0
```

Comment: I believe that instead of `sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-5.0`  it could work with `sudo apt install -y dotnet-sdk-5.0` as well.

Comment: Definitely the best approach. Last 5 times I have used snap for installing I have immediately regretted it. Snap is just bad software. Apt is better.

Answer (score 0):

Remove snap first
`sudo snap remove dotnet-sdk`
Manually download Dotnet SDK https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0

When your download completes, open the terminal and run the following commands to extract the SDK to make the commands available at the terminal.

```
mkdir -p $HOME/dotnet && tar zxf dotnet-sdk-6.0.101-linux-x64.tar.gz -C $HOME/dotnet
export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/dotnet
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dotnet
```

one last thing
[Edit shell profile to permanently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6f16.png)